# Java not passing all the web service parameter to the Source after JBoss Migration

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I am calling a Web service and in the request I am passing an Array, But at the publisher's side one value from the array is missing.
This was working perfectly before the Migration. 
Note: We were Using OC4G but now Migrated to JBoss.

I tried with the fiddler and checked that from my website the request contains All the fields but when it is hitting the publisher side one field is missing.

This is a search functionality in my website and when i click the search button it will call the web service. The strange behavior is that it passes the correct parameters when i click on the search for third time all the values will be passed to the publisher and i will get the response, not for the first two times :(

Comment: It probably very helpful to show the issue with a little piece of code / debug logs / .. Just text is hard to imagine. Also your use of source/publisher seems the wrong way round (Things go from a publisher / source to a subscriber / sink)?

Comment: JBoss what? JBoss AS? JBoss EAP? WildFly? JBoss web services? JBoss Enterprise Web Server?